# Does Ubuntu support 64 bit CPUs?

Tags: 64-bit

Am thinking of upgrading to a new laptop (64 bit) and would like to install Ubuntu 12.04 or newer.  Are they compatible?

Comment: Ubuntu has been compatible with 64 bit since a bunch of versions ago. You need to include what hardware you have but I have installed Ubuntu in several laptops that are 64 bit compatible with no problems.

Comment: I thought *for sure* this was a duplicate when I first read it. +1, good question but I can't believe nobody asked it yet...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to install either the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Ubuntu on a 64-bit computer. Ubuntu has been released with both options since the very beginning (e.g. [warty warthog from november 2004](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/4.10/)).

The version with an **i386** in the name is the 32-bit version and the one with **amd64** is the one for 64-bit computers. Don't let the "i" or "amd" confuse you, it's the numbers that matter.

Also take a look at [Ubuntu Certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) hardware and the user-feedback at the [Ubuntu Friendly](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/) pages.

Comment: why would you include a link to an unsupported and very old version of Ubuntu? just curious to what your thought process was...

Comment: @Joshua I think they are linking to the earliest version with 64-bit support?

Comment: @TomBrossman maybe...

Comment: @Joshua I was trying to show proof of my previous statement, which is more obvious after Tom Brossman (thankfully) cleaned up my mess. I did not really think that one through.

Answer (score 3):

Yes all you have to do is go to [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com), select the 64 bit version, download, burn, and install as you normally would.

[image]

Here is the direct [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts) for Ubuntu 12.04.